# CSS HTML fixing a div on a certain point in a parent image

Tags: html, css, svg

I', hoping this makes sense but I have HTML code that I have a child which is an svg animation, I'm wanting to have the section responsive so that the position of the svg stays where its meant to be on the map.

I have selected the coast of Africa as a point that I want to keep the SVG in place when the page is resized, but when it is resized you will see that the red marker moves across the rest of Africa.

You can see the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fge98sz0/1/) for the Source Code and [see the result](http://jsfiddle.net/fge98sz0/1/embedded/result/) to the full map.

```
.about-header__map .angola {
    position: inherit;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.about-header__map .angola svg {
    top: 49%;
    left: 42.5%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the width of the image (1440px) instead of width:100%

```
.about-header__map {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/ZqQvEUK.png) no-repeat center center !important;
    width: 1440px; /*here */
    background-size: cover;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/fge98sz0/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use a fixed width in .about-header__map

```
.about-header__map {
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/ZqQvEUK.png) no-repeat center center !important;
background-size: cover;
height: 500px;
position: absolute;
width: 1500px;
z-index: -1;
}
```